# Cucumber in a scenario session does not persist

Tags: cucumber

Trying to get test the scenario where user logs (admin) and then create further users.

In log i can see that control goes to login page and then admin user logs in and when control redirects to further users creation page the login filter get halts and redirect control back to login page.

Newbie in cucumber so code is not good in quality, so any guide for testing logged in user services will be helpful

Here is my scnario

```
Feature: Create user from LMS
  In order to create lms user with multiple groups
  As a author
  I want to create lms user with multipl groups

  Scenario: Add  new user with multiple groups
      Given the following user information
      And I am logged in as author "gulled" with password "thebest"
      When I request for new lms user creation
      Then the new user "user1" should be created
```

And here is the deffinitions

```
Given /^the following user information$/ do 
  # Factory(:login)
  # Factory(:author)
end

Given /^I am logged in as author "([^"]*)" with password "([^"]*)"$/ do |username, password|
  visit "account/login"
  fill_in "loginfield", :with => username   
  fill_in "password", :with => password
  click_button "submit_button"  
end

When /^I request for new lms user creation$/ do
  visit "/author_backend_lms/new_user"  
  fill_in "login_first_name", :with => ""
  fill_in "login_last_name", :with => ""
  fill_in "login_login", :with => ""
  fill_in "login_email", :with => ""
  fill_in "login_password_confirmation", :with => ""
  click_button "create_user_form_submit_button"
end

Then /^the new user "([^"]*)" should be created$/ do |user_login|
  login = Login.find_by_login user
  assert_no_nil login, "Record creation failed" 
end
```

In "request for new lms user creation" the control redirects back to login page when try to access lms user creation page.

Here is my Gem list for test

```
gem "capybara", "1.1.1"
gem "cucumber", "1.1.0"
gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not creating the admin user beforehand in the `Given the following user information` step, which is making the `And I am logged in as author "gulled" with password "thebest"` step fail.

Try using [`save_and_open_page` method](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/ever-heard-of-capybaras-save_and_open_page-method/) to debug what is happening after each step.

I would rewrite the scenario as follows(without having too many unwanted detail):

```
Scenario: Add  new user with multiple groups
  Given I am logged in as an admin user
  When I request for new lms user creation
  Then a new user should be created
```

Do check out http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off for some good advice on how to write better scenarios.

***EDIT***

Here's an example step_definitions from one of my projects for creating the user beforehand, and logging in:

```
Given /^the user has an account$/ do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create( :user )
end

When /^the user submits valid signin information$/ do
  fill_in "user_email",    with: @user.email
  fill_in "user_password", with: @user.password 
  click_button "Sign in"
  page.should have_link('Logout', href: destroy_user_session_path)
end
```

Using instance variables makes the user factory object persist across steps. And checking that there is a `logout` link at the end of the step ensures that the signin has indeed succeeded. Hope this helps in fine-tuning your step definitions.

Comment: yes changes the code but still fails, in first step user gets logged in and when "WHEN" case executed the authentication system raise error 

Processing AuthorBackendContentController#index  [GET]
{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"author_backend_content"}
Redirected to http://www.example.com/account/login
Filter chain halted as [:login_required] rendered_or_redirected.
[http://www.example.com/author_backend_content]
  REQUESTING PAGE: GET http://www.example.com/account/logi

Comment: `Redirected to example.com/account/login` => Looks like the user login did not succeed. Are you using `save_and_open_page` to debug the issue?

Comment: yes used it and on each step it keeps stay (show) the login page.

Comment: So the user login is not succeeding. Looks like you are not creating the user/author with `name => "gulled"` and `password => "thebest"`, but trying to login with those credentials.

Comment: Edited the answer to include an example; hope it will be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the comments .... dont know how but replacing webrat with capybara things starts working normal. May be some configuration of webrat are wither messed or missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample project which illustrates better (IMO) ways of using Cucumber to do this sort of thing. I think it might provide some of the guidance you asked for

[see here](https://github.com/diabolo/r3-mongo-devise)

Hope its useful